# SQL Server 2016 JSON: Select array of strings instead of array of objects

Tags: arrays, sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I am new to JSON in SQL Server and can't figure out how to return a simple array of strings:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE ([value] NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('foo')
INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('bar')
INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('test')
INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('ok')

SELECT [value]
FROM @T
FOR JSON PATH
```

This returns an array of objects:

```json
[{"value":"foo"},{"value":"bar"},{"value":"test"},{"value":"ok"}]
```

I would like it to return:

```
["foo","bar","test","ok"]
```

Can this even be done?

Comment: What I learn from this Q&A = SQL Server 2016 advertises JSON support but does not provide a straightforward way to query a table and return an array in JSON format. Why on Earth should we have to be building the array string manually? Ugh.

Answer (score 12):

Building on Loui Bao and Roman's answer:

```
declare @t table ([value] nvarchar(max))

insert into @t ([value]) values ('foo')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('bar')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('test')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('ok')

SELECT
    JSON_QUERY((SELECT CONCAT('["',STRING_AGG([value], '","'),'"]') FROM @t)) As MuhArray
    OtherValue,
    AnotherValue
FROM MyTableOValues
FOR JSON PATH
```

This is creating a JSON valid array of simple values and assigning it to the property MuhArray. The JSON output from this would be:

```
[{
  MuhArray: ["foo", "bar", "test", "ok"],
  OtherValue: "Value",
  AnotherValue: "AnotherValue"
}]
```

Where `OtherValue` and `AnotherValue` receive whatever corresponding values were in the table. With some fiddling you could also choose not to build this as a subquery in the select list, but as a simple join in the main query body. In my view, using subqueries in the select list can remove the need for the `distinct` keyword.

Answer (score 8):

In AdventureWorks 2016 CTP3 JSON sample you can find a function that can clean array of key:value pairs and create array od values:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.ufnToRawJsonArray
GO
CREATE FUNCTION
[dbo].[ufnToRawJsonArray](@json nvarchar(max), @key nvarchar(400)) returns nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN
       declare @new nvarchar(max) = replace(@json, CONCAT('},{"', @key,'":'),',')
       return '[' + substring(@new, 1 + (LEN(@key)+5), LEN(@new) -2 - (LEN(@key)+5)) + ']'
END
```

Just provide result of your SELECT FOR JSON expression as @json parameter and name of the key that you want to remove as second parameter. Probably something like:

```
select dbo.ufnToRawJsonArray( (SELECT value FROM mytable for json path), 'value')
```

Answer (score 8):

In SQL2017, use STRING_AGG instead of json. This function is the best for generating comma-separated lists of values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql

```
SELECT town, STRING_AGG (email, ';') AS emails 
FROM dbo.Employee 
GROUP BY town;
```

Comment: This breaks if I do `insert into @t ([value]) values ('test " , '' ')`, as while `for json path` handles char escaping `string_agg` corrupts the output. This is only faster if you're sure the source doesn't contain any chars that need escaping.

Comment: STRING_ESCAPE to help with that.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 5):

Building on top of Roman's answer:

```
declare @t table ([value] nvarchar(max))

insert into @t ([value]) values ('foo')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('bar')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('test')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('ok')

select concat('[', string_agg(concat('"', [value], '"'), ','), ']')
from @t
```

output:

`["foo","bar","test","ok"]`

Answer (score 2):

**Use the following code with any versions from Sql Server 2016**

```
declare @t table ([value] nvarchar(max))

insert into @t ([value]) values ('foo')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('bar')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('test')
insert into @t ([value]) values ('ok')

DECLARE @values nvarchar(max) = N'[]'; 
SELECT @values = JSON_MODIFY(@values,'append $',[value]) 
FROM @t SELECT @values
```

Comment: You can just do
`
DECLARE @values nvarchar(max) = N'[]';
SELECT @values = JSON_MODIFY(@values,'append $',[value]) FROM @t

SELECT @values` actually

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([value] NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('foo')
INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('bar')
INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('test')
INSERT INTO @T ([value]) VALUES ('ok')

SELECT JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF((SELECT ',"' +  [value] + '"' from  @T FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')+']')
```

Returns:

```
["foo","bar","test","ok"]
```

Comment: solution that doesn't need a procedure/function

Comment: This is what I needed, and the JSON_QUERY is needed to output JSON object, otherwise it outputs an escaped string containing JSON

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  2016 has a few ways of working with JSON.  This method defines the JSON string, pulls the values out of it, then uses XML tricks to get the multiple rows into one row.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([value] NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @T ([value])
VALUES ('foo')

INSERT INTO @T ([value])
VALUES ('bar')

INSERT INTO @T ([value])
VALUES ('test')

INSERT INTO @T ([value])
VALUES ('ok')

DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
        SELECT *
        FROM @T
        FOR JSON PATH
        );

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (NAME VARCHAR(10) '$.value')
    )
SELECT QUOTENAME(left(names, LEN(names) - 1) )AS names
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (
            SELECT QUOTENAME(NAME,'"') + ',' AS [text()]
            FROM cte
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) names
    FROM cte
    ) x
```