# SQL to JSON - array of objects to array of values with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

How to make the query below work?

I used the concept from another question [SQL Server 2016 JSON: Select array of strings instead of array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948323/2057854)

But when I tried the select below it doesn't work

```
SELECT
    (SELECT line AS "line"  
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              CONCAT('5th', ' ', '566') AS "line"
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Complement' AS LINE
         )
     FOR JSON PATH) AS "address.lines"
```

The version of the SQL Server `SELECT @@VERSION` = `Microsoft SQL Server 2016`

The result from the query is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

The excepted result is `[{"line":"5th 566"},{"line":"Complement"}]`, with this result I will use the function from [SQL Server 2016 JSON: Select array of strings instead of array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948323/2057854) to remove "line" and get the final result `["5th 566","Complement"]`

I need to use the `UNION ALL` because I have two different values from the same table to result in an array called `address.lines` at the JSON result

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need an alias (`t`) to solve this error:

Statement:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT [Line] FROM (
        SELECT CONCAT('5th', ' ',  '566') AS [Line]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Complement' AS [Line]
    ) t
    FOR JSON PATH
)
AS "address.lines"
```

Output:

```
address.lines
[{"Line":"5th 566"},{"Line":"Complement"}]
```

Of course, you can use only `JSON` functions to generate the final `JSON` output:

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[]'
SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, 'append $', [Line])
FROM (
   SELECT CONCAT('5th', ' ',  '566') AS [Line]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Complement' AS [Line]
) t
SELECT @json AS [address.lines]
```

Output:

```
address.lines
["5th 566","Complement"]
```